# The Firewall-cmd direct rules will remain after deletion

Tags: centos7, firewall-cmd

When the firewall is running, I cannot access my website. When I turn it off, it works.

**I used these rules** to redirect port 8443 to regular 443.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -o lo --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443

firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

I don´t need them anymore (run Apache proxy). **I try to delete them**:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --direct --remove-rule ipv4 nat OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -o lo --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443

firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --direct --remove-rule ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

Rules didn´t disappear. I found them in iptables. I **flushed nat iptables** use the command:

```
iptables -t nat -F
```

After the flush I can connect to the website. When I restart my computer, the rules still remain and the web page is unavailable. How do I permanently delete the rules? Are the commands correct?

**firewall-cmd configuration:**

```
root@my_hostname]# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=public

public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: ssh https http
  ports:  443/tcp 44443/tcp 8443/tcp 8081/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** After performing iptables-flush and after re-running commands again, the rules were permanently deleted. It's strange that running firewall-cmd --remove commands themselves didn't help.